# JS Regex match last occurence between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to retrieve data between last brackets occurence from this text :

```
"Some text [Rewex] [1246] • 3/21/21 9PM • [**3646**]"
```

With

```
let id = text.match(/(\[)(?!.*\1)(.*)\]/g);
```

[Example link](https://regex101.com/r/KT54ly/1)

I can retrieve **[3646]** but I only want **3646** (data between brackets)

Is there a way to do this with regex or do I have to do it with replace() ?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: Is it always the end of the line? Or can there be text after it? What is not working for yours since it seems like it is there?

Comment: You already have the value in capture group 2, but you don't need any lookahead `^.*\[(\d+)][^\][]*$` https://regex101.com/r/oulj9s/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex to match a last occurrence of characters in the last set of angle brackets:

```
/(?![^\[]*\[)[^\]]+(?=\])/
```

https://regex101.com/r/04ZFZo/1

In short, to break it down:

```sh
(?![^\[]*\[) Lookahead and greedily consume everything that is not an [ till a final [
[^\]]+       (Get ID) Everything that is not an ] one or more characters
(?=\])       till the first ] occurrence (ignored from matching).
```

The above will return `3646` for a string like

> Some text [Rewex] [1246] • 3/21/21 9PM • [**3646**] foo bar baz

If instead you want to get both `1246` **and** `3646` that's even simpler https://regex101.com/r/HpfziG/1:

```
/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/g
```

where `\d+` stands for: *one or more digits*.
If it's a mixed characters content - use `[^\]]+` (*not an ] one or more times*) like:

```
/(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\])/g
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the explanation !

Comment: @Padd you're welcome! PS added a slight modification to the regex I initially posted.